# I need help connecting to system running as gateway

Tags: routing, router, subnet, ip-forwarding

I need some help with a new network I set up. I have a network setup according to the [Masquerade Alternative on this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/965742), with the tap and bridge, and everything is mostly working.

Here's a (bad) sketch of the topology:

(internet - via WiFi) <-> (arch linux pc with tap/bridge) <-> (router) <-> (router) <-> (other arch linux)

So, internet comes in over WiFi. The pc with the tap/bridge is connected to the WiFi and is bridging the connection to eth (while still being able to access internet itself). That pc is connected to a router about a foot away, which hosts a subnet. This router is also providing connection to another router about 30 ft away via ethernet. And that far away router has its own subnet.

What I'm trying to do, is connect to a TCP server running on the pc with the tap/bridge from a client pc under the far away router.

The two PC's are on different subnets (the tap/bridge pc has the ip 192.168.1.69, and the other has the ip 192.168.254.27). The gateway the tapped/bridged pc gets internet from uses subnet 192.168.1.0, the first router uses subnet 192.168.100.0, and the far away router uses subnet 192.168.254.0.

Any help is appreciated. I could always fall-back to using a middleman server on the net somewhere, but I know there's an easier way to do this, maybe with ip forwarding or something, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is more appropriate for superuser.com then serverfault.  You should also add the netmasks for your subnets, and the IP addresses of the various interfaces - especially on the router.  There are at least a couple of solutions - either by using NAT and port forwarding, or by routing within the network - but we don't have sufficient information to advise.   Also, how does the Linux PC with bridge interface and the router share the IP space?  Lastly, why do you have such a rube-goldberg network setup?

Comment: Is your arch linux PC acting as a bridge or as a router?

Comment: @davidgo sorry for the delay, acting as bridge

Comment: and the laptop gets ip in the 192.168.1.255 range from its router, and the router connected to it gets the range 192.168.100.255. As for the awkward setup, I rent two separate houses very close by eachother (separated by a driveway), and needed to get internet from one to the other without paying isp extra for another setup, or running a long cable, so a laptop connects to that, bridges connection over to local router, which used to be plugged into the old isp (not their router).

Comment: Your setup is very hard to grasp (I still don't fully get it), and needlessly complex to achieve your goals. I suspect the issue is with NAT or bridging and your 2 routers, but you have provided far to little info in terms of interfaces, IP addresses, netmasks and routers. You might want to post a post on superuser.com with what you are trying to achieve and rebuild your network more simply in line with best practice's. (I strongly suspect you are bridging where you should be routing for a start)